# ShowAlertDialog on WindowManager

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, window-managers

I have a customView added on the WindowManager

```
WindowManager mWm = (WindowManager)activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWm.addView(customView, mWl);
```

When customView is clicked, i will show a alert dialog.
However, the alertDialog is shown behind the customView.

Any way to add the alert dialog on WindowManager or just in front of everything?

Comment: What type of Layout does this view contain? You can specify the z-index of your `customView` in the appropriate layout params...

Comment: the customView extends RelativeLayout and contain webview, imageview and imagebutton. As I pass a "context" to the `AlertDialog.Builder`, I think the problem is the alert dialog is show on the application layer and the customView is show on the windowmanager

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like what you want is an activity view that's transparent with an alert dialog in front of that.

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ClassName"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
</activity>
```

and then user the activity's `showDialog` method to create the dialog